# How to efficiently compare images in Python using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl data from `https://mongolia.gogo.mn/` and `https://gogo.mn/` where there are bilingual data - Mongolian and English version of the same article. However it is impossible to automatically crawl the data and map which English article correspond to its Mongolian article because their URLs are drastically different. For example, `https://mongolia.gogo.mn/r/162466` and `https://gogo.mn/r/2e313`. What's same is that the image they used.

I have written a code that compares images.

```
var=`compare -metric AE $1 $2 null: 2>&1`
echo $var
```

which return 0 if the two images are exactly the same. So my plan is to get every article from Mongolian website with its images, and get every English article and once I have the pictures, to compare them. However, the website contains a massive amount of articles that it would take so long to compare every picture in Mongolian with every picture in English.

How can I map the articles from the two sides and make sure they correspond to each other?

In the end I want output file like

```
https://gogo.mn/r/2e313,https://mongolia.gogo.mn/r/162466
another_article_en,another_article_mn
```

Comment: I don't think you need to compare the images, just the source.

Comment: @Julia that's what I thought at first, but then I realized that there are images that are the same but have different names. So it's safer to compare the images

Comment: For me, they are the exactly same (`https://eu.gogo.mn/newsn/thumbnail/1000/images/c/2020/07/259193-31072020-1596164607-1964811574-ф.jpg` in both cases)

Comment: @Julia yes you are corrent. But there are other articles that has different image names.

Comment: Compare image sizes first, run your compare script only for images of exactly the same size.